# Dispatch after Facebook Login (React)

Tags: facebook, reactjs, api, redux

I'm pretty new in React and I'm trying to integrate Facebook login, after read a lot of blogs I don't have problems with Facebook Api but I can't make it works in my App, I'm getting this message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined", I'm working with React/Redux, any advice?

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    window.FB.init({
      appId      : 'ID',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });

    window.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', (response) => {
    if (response.authResponse){
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api(
        '/me',
        'GET',
        {"fields":"id,name,email"},
        function(response) {
            this.props.dispatch(login(response.email, response.id, true),)
          }
        );
     } else{
        this.updateLoggedOutState()
     }   
    });
  }.bind(this);

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
let dispatch = {this.props.dispatch};
window.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', (response) => {
    if (response.authResponse){
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api(
            '/me',
            'GET',
            {"fields":"id,name,email"},
            function(response) {
                dispatch(login(response.email, response.id, true),)
            }
        );
    } else{
        this.updateLoggedOutState()
    }   
});
```

Comment: Works! with out { } in "let dispatch = {this.props.dispatch};", thank you.